# Unable to export in JSON file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

The following code does export in CSV file format, but it does not export in JSON format.
I don't know what the problem is maybe it is because I can't use `crawl` syntax in my scrapy spider and I use `runspider` syntax instead.

```
import scrapy
# from bookscraper.items import bootitem 
class BookspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bookspider"
    allowed_domains = ["books.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        
        books = response.css('article.product_pod')

        for book in books:

            relative_url = book.css('h3 a').attrib['href']

            if 'catalogue/' in relative_url:
                book_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/' + relative_url
            else:
                book_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/' + relative_url
            
            yield scrapy.Request(book_url, callback=self.parse_book_page)

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        
        if next_page is not None:
            if 'catalogue/' in next_page:
                next_page_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/' + next_page
            else:
                next_page_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/' + next_page
            
            yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_book_page(self, response):
     
        table_rows = response.css('table tr')
       #scra book_item = bookitem()
        yield{
                'url' : response.url,
                'title': response.css('.product_main h1::text'),
                'product_type': table_rows[1].css('td::text'),
                'price_excl_tax': table_rows[2].css('td::text'),
                'price_incl_tax': table_rows[3].css('td::text'),
                'tax' : table_rows[4].css('td::text'),
                'availability' : table_rows[5].css('td::text'),
                'num_reviews': table_rows[6].css('td::text'),
                'stars': response.css('p.star-rating').attrib['class'],
                'category': response.xpath("//ul[@class='breadcrumb']/li[@class='active']/preceding-sibling::li[1]/a/text()").get(),
                'description': response.xpath("//div[@id='product_description']/following-sibling::p/text()").get(),
                'price': response.css('p.price-color::text'),
        }
```

When I export in `JSON` file it only exports a file full of commas on each line

Comment: Where's your "export in JSON" code?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are returning a JSON object in which some properties are Selectors:

```
yield{
  'url' : response.url,
  'title': response.css('.product_main h1::text') # This returns a Selector object,
  'product_type': table_rows[1].css('td::text'),
...
```

The selectors, when serialized to string, produce some characters that are illegal in a JSON file, but work fine as strings in a CSV file.

If you use the `.get()` at the end of those lines, you should be fine.